# How to link one x-axis to another y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the `sharex` parameter to a `add_subplot`, I can link two plots' x axes. However, how can I link one plot's x axis to another ones y axis?

MnWE: (n stands for non)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
y = np.sin(x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, sharex=ax1.yaxis)  # AttributeError: 'YAxis' object has no attribute 'xaxis'
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(y,x)  # since x and y are swapped, ax2.xaxis should be linked to ax1.yaxis (and vice versa)
```

Comment: Is the end goal that ax2's xaxis have the same ticks and ticklabels as ax1's yaxis?

Comment: @BigBen Indeed, and also that interactive actions such as zooming influence both, i.e. something about callbacks etc